# Question about repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, glmm

I have a dataset in which, for some individuals, I measure phenotypes in one or both arms (meaning some patients might have the phenotype measured only on the left or right arm, and for others, I have measurements in both arms). in the case that I measure it in both arms, I know these are correlated measures. I have considered using a linear mixed effects model. Am I correct in wanting to use lmms? Would the random effect, in this case, be the individual ID?

Thanks

Comment: If I've correctly understood the structure of your data, it appears to be a plausible approach to analyze it using `... + (1 | ID)` within the framework of `lme4`.